# Extract spefic block of data from Execl workbook to another work book

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I am using SSIS and I want to search for a block of data in the main sheet and then copy it to another workbook. How can this be done ?

Comment: How have you tried to do it, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have tried to use excel source and access it by SQL Command   SELECT[Main$A34:D180] but my Bids just crashes. And its not the best thing to do since the position of the block I want to select my change every month

Comment: Bids shouldn't crash.  Maybe you've got a corrupted installation or some kind of system problem.

Comment: Still don't have any idea how to do this